# Storyboard - Open UIViewController as UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

For my iPad version of the app I want to open my `UIViewController` as a `UIPopoverController` from the click of a button. So, the real code for view controller opening is below. How can I easily convert such code into opening a `UIViewController` as a `UIPopoverController`?

Code:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary        objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UIViewController *aboutView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutViewController"];
aboutView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:aboutView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: just use the popover segue in storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIPopoverController *poc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:aboutView];
    [poc presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(somePoint.x, somePointY, 1.0, 1.0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
} else {
    aboutView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:aboutView animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

You can also present the popover from a button and you also can control the direction in which the popover will be presented. If you use `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny`, iOS will make a smart decision for the popover to be visible.

You should also keep a strong reference to your popover and only present it while it is `nil` to make sure the popover is only present once. That means if the popover is dismissed, set the property holding it to `nil`.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to know how to dismiss it. I would think [self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; does the trick but compiler does not see it because it is a view controller.

Comment: Apple about the dismissPopoverAnimated: `You can use this method to dismiss the popover programmatically in response to taps inside the popover window. Taps outside of the popover’s contents automatically dismiss the popover.` So if you need to dismiss it in the code, you need to call it on the popover viewcontroller itself, not the presenting one. Also, if the poc is dismissed automatically, use its delegate method `- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` to set the pointer to it to nil as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to have two storyboards, one for iPhone, one for iPad. That way you can use the popover segue in the iPad storyboard and the modal segue in the iPhone storyboard. You can readily arrange your Info.plist so that the correct storyboard loads automatically at launch time. You will still need some conditional code, though, since your code will respond differently to having a presented view controller than having a popover.